# Annotating Flot chart based on y-axis position

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, flot

I'm trying to annotate a Flot.js chart; based on [this](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/annotating/index.html) example, this is done by adding an absolutely-positioned div which floats over the canvas, which is fine when you have a single chart with a fixed width and static content. The problem is that this approach breaks under two conditions: one, when working with a fluid-width layout (using the Resize plugin), and two, when dynamically redrawing the chart object at varying sizes, say, such as [when implementing a zooming overview chart](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/visitors/index.html).

For my question specifically, I need to draw in the annotations at certain parts of the Y-Axis. I know I can add a vertical bar to mark these points fairly easily by using markings, but that doesn't really help tell my program where to draw in the annotation markings. I suspect that it might be a matter of adding a custom hook at the Drawing phase of the chart, but I'm not completely sure; what's the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do this, specifically using the axis.p2c function. Here's an example function which uses this logic to draw a caret pointing at the current time:

```
window.TimePointer = function(plot, currentTime) {
    // Get the currente axes
    var axes = plot.getAxes();
    var xaxis = axes.xaxis;
    var yaxis = axes.yaxis;

    var element = plot.getPlaceholder();

    // Find the chart icon element
    var pointer = element.find('.time-pointer');

    // Check that the intended point is inside the visible area
    if((currentTime < xaxis.max) && (currentTime > xaxis.min)) {
        if(pointer.length == 0) {
            // If it doesn't exist already, create it
            element.append('<i class="time-pointer icon-caret-down"></i>');
            pointer = element.find('.time-pointer');
        }

        var plotOffset = plot.offset();
        var offset = {
            top: plotOffset.top - pointer.height(),
            left: xaxis.p2c(currentTime) + plotOffset.left - (pointer.outerWidth()/2)
        };
        pointer.offset(offset);
    } else {
        // If the currently selected area doesn't contain the point, erase the pointer
        pointer.remove();
    }
}
```

The key line is in the offset calculation

```
xaxis.p2c(time) + plotOffset.left - (pointer.outerwidth()/2)
```

Based on this, I can also add time-based annotations to my chart at any given point in time by following the same logic. Note that it would probably be ideal to bind this function to the chart's drawOverlay phase so as to take full advantage of things like the resize event.